# Why my responsive layout doesn't work? CSS issue, float: none; seems not be working

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my layout responsive by media queries, but when I scale down my browser the elements float to left.

Why float: none; does not work here? Is this the right way of fixing it?

Thank you in advance.

```css
.row { width: 100%; max-width: 940px; min-width: 320px; margin: 0 auto; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) { .row { padding: 0 20px; } }

.row .row { min-width: 0px; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) { .row .row { padding: 0; } }

.column, .columns { margin-left: 2.12766%; float: left; min-height: 1px; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

.column:first-child, .columns:first-child, .alpha { margin-left: 0px; }

.row .six.columns { width: 48.93617%; margin-bottom:20px;}


@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { body { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; -ms-text-size-adjust: none; width: 100%; min-width: 0; }
  .container { min-width: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; }
  .row { width: 100%; min-width: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; }
  .row .row .column, .row .row .columns { padding: 0; }
  .row .centered { margin: 0 !important; }
  .column, .columns { width: auto !important; float: none; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; }
  .column:last-child, .columns:last-child { margin-right: 0; float: none; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="six columns inline">
                <div class="services-box services-box-animated">
                    <div class="inner">
                     <div class="front">
                         <img src="img/evolution2.png" id="evolution"/>
                          <h4>Discovery</h4>
                     </div>
                     <div class="back">
                          <p>Whatever goes here.</p>
                     </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
        </div>

            <div class="six columns inline">
                    <div class="services-box services-box-animated">
                    <div class="inner">
                         <div class="front">
                         <img src="img/evolution2.png" id="evolution"/>
                          <h4>Discovery</h4>
                     </div>
                     <div class="back">
                          <p>Whatever goes here.</p>
                     </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
<!--third div goes here-->
             </div>
```

Comment: Please don't use the code snippet feature if there's nothing to demonstrate.  In this case, the "run code" button results in a blank page because you have no content in your `div` elements.

Comment: Try putting your code online in a format that demonstrates the problem simply. You can use something like JSFiddle - I put your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/xe7m3fj7/ . If possible, please explicitly state the behaviour you're seeing, and the desired behaviour.

Comment: how do you want the layout? do you have an image of how you want it to layout. also it may help if you send a full page with the basic layout of the regions.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm totally new in here. @Crummy that's exactly what I want, divs be on top of each other when browser size reduces. It's interesting that it's working on JSFiddle that you've made and not working on my computer.

Comment: In that case, try filling the JSFiddle with more of your HTML and CSS until the problem reproduces, then posting it here.